# assertion failed (a_size.width == len) in cv::gemm

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

```
#include <opencv2\core\core.hpp>
#include<opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>
#include<opencv2\highgui\highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include<conio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
Mat im= imread("D:\\try.jpg"),newface,A;
Mat im2 = imread("D:\\project\\barc\\variables\\Eigenface.jpg");

cvtColor(im, im, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cvtColor(im2, im2, CV_BGR2GRAY);

resize(im, im, Size(48, 48));
newface = im.reshape(0, 2304);

newface.convertTo(newface, CV_32FC1);
im2.convertTo(im2, CV_32FC1);

cout << "Diff : " << newface.size() << "\t" << "channels" << newface.channels() <<  endl;
cout << "Eigen : " << im2.size() << "\t" << "channels" << im2.channels() << endl;

A = im2*newface.t();

_getch();

return 0;
}
```

The Eigenface.jpg is of dimension (9x2304). When i am multiplying with the image i am facing this error is coming can anyone help?

Comment: how do you do the multiplication?

Comment: i have used simple test_omega = Eigenface*(diff_test_image.t());

Comment: Can you post the code? the construction of the matrix? If Eigenface is 2304x1 then that is the problem...

Comment: no sir Eigenface is (9x2304) and diff_test_image is (1x2304)

Comment: I have uploaded teh code can you now tell me what is the problem

Comment: yes, I have updated the answer too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check that for matrix M1,M2
M1.cols == M2.rows.
If they are not equal then the multiplication is not possible!

Answer (score 0):

Print matrix width (cols) and height (rows) and see the problem: `Eigenface.cols = 9` and `diff_test_image.rows = 2304`. The two must be equal to do the multiplication. Do:

```
test_omega = (Eigenface.t())*diff_test_image;
```

---

**Edit after code:**

What does it prints in the line of `cout << "Diff : " << newface.size() << "\t" << "channels" << newface.channels() <<  endl;` ? What about the next one? Is the `Eigenface.jpg` of size `9x2304`? I do not think so...

Even if `im2.rows == 2304`, you are multiplying with a column vector that should be in front of `im2` or just try `newface = im.reshape(0, 1);` for having a column vector so it's transpose will be a row vector

Answer (score 0):

```
Mat M1(9,2304,CV_32F, Scalar(1));
Mat M2(2304,1, CV_32F, Scalar(2));

Mat M3 = M1 * M2;

cerr << M3.size() << endl;
cerr << M3 << endl;
```

---

```
[1 x 9]
[4608; 4608; 4608; 4608; 4608; 4608; 4608; 4608; 4608]
```

---

(btw, if you meant to do a subspace-projection there, you will have to subtract the mean from diff_test_image first)

Comment: can you do it by using transpose of M2 kepping M2 as (1x2304)

Comment: no. it's either either col-Vec * Matrix, or Matrix * row-Vec

Comment: we cannot use t(operator) while multiplying

Comment: I have two matrix :  M1 has size (9x2304)   M2 has size (1x2304)   i have performing calculation  M3 = M1*(M2.t())  Is it wrong?

Comment: but it is showing this error can you just tell me what does it mean

Comment: no idea, what you're doing now. again, the rule is simple:  col-Vec * Matrix, or Matrix * row-Vec